# How do I obtain an HtmlHelper<TModel> instance for a model in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have an Index view. The model I pass in is actually a collection of models, so the `Html` property is of type `HtmlHelper<List<MyModel>>`. If I want to call extension methods (e.g., `Display()` or `DisplayFor()` on the individual items in the list, however, I think I need to obtain an `HtmlHelper<MyModel>`. But how?

I tried using the `HtmlHelper<TModel>` constructor, which looks like this:

```
HtmlHelper<TModel>(ViewContext, IViewDataContainer)
```

But I'm not having any luck with that. I don't know how to obtain the `IViewDataContainer` for the item, and the documentation on these things is very sparse.

A lot of magic apparently happens when I do...

```
return View(List<MyModel>);
```

...in my controller.

How do I recreate that magic on individual items in a list/collection?

**Update**

Here is a code snippet to show what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            var helper = new HtmlHelper<ProjName.MyModel>(ViewContext, ????);
%>
            <tr>
<%
                foreach(var property in properties)
                {
%>
                    <td>
                        <%=  helper.Display(property.DisplayName) %>
                    </td>
<%          
                }
%>
            </tr>
<%
        }
```

Basically, I want to populate the cells of a table using the items in the collection. I just need help setting the `helper` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack to the rescue!

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use RenderPartial. So create a user control which has the type of your model (MyModel). Then in your main view, add the following code.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SubView", property); %>
```

So the main view would look like:

```
 foreach(var item in items) 
 { 
    %> 
    <tr> 
    <% 
        foreach(var property in properties) 
        { 
         %> 
            <td> 
                <%= Html.RenderPartial("SubView", property) %> 
            </td> 
        <%           
        } 
        %> 
    </tr> 
    <% 
    }
    %>
```

Then the sub view would be a strongly typed user control of type . The sub view can then just call the helper and it will be of the correct type:

```
<%= Html.Display(Model.DisplayName) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The page itself is a `IViewDataContainer`. You could try that :</strike>

```
foreach(MyModel m in Model)
{
    HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper<MyModel>(ViewContext, this);
    ...
}
```

UPDATE

Another idea : you could create a `ViewUserControl<MyModel>` and use `RenderPartial` to render each item with this control. `ViewUserControl<MyModel>` exposes a `HtmlHelper<MyModel>` that you can use to render the model

Comment: I get a runtime exception: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `List<MyModel>` but the dictionary requires a model item of type `MyModel`."

Comment: That's pretty much what my previous attempt was. The problem was, it took like 30 seconds for about 250 records. I think the problem was that the LINQ query that generates the `properties` had to be run 250 times instead of just once because I couldn't see an obvious way to pass the `properties` into the `MyModel` template. So, I decided to just simplify to one page until I could get it working, then divide things up into generic helper extension methods for easy reuse. Unfortunately, simplifying to one page has proven not to be a simplification :( Thanks for the idea though :)

Comment: I should add, I really can't build the extensions until I get this one-page solution working because I still need an `HtmlHelper` that is specific to each individual item in the collection. So, whether I use a template or extension methods, I can't build it without solving the problem first.